# SQL transpose multi column table without aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, multiple-columns, transpose

I have a dataset in the format;

[image: Existing Data]

And need to it in the format;

[image: Desired Format]

I have had various attempts at pivot and unpivot for the last week but am not a real programmer and know when to ask a grownup for help.

The database is running on MSSQL 2012 and the dataset will consist of 14 Mode_Antibiotics, ModeQualifier and ModeMIC entries per ClinicalTrialID with a total of approximately 3000 ClinicalTrialIDs.

Comment: Are there some type-o's in you expected results? It seems like the mode_qualifier isn't consistent between the two tables.

Comment: I don't have time to do this right now, although it quite enticing. this link may help https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kenobonn/2009/03/22/pivot-on-two-or-more-fields-in-sql-server/

Comment: It was a cut and paste example from the format requestor...i have updated the image...thanks for noticing

Comment: Thanks for the link StelioK...I will look at it over the weekend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's going to be hard to do it in pure SQL dynamically. If I new T-SQL, I would write a table function returning the required dataset. However, in a pure ANSI SQL, since you don't have that many columns, you could use something like this:

```
SELECT 
  ClinicalTrialID,
  MAX(CASE 
    WHEN Mode_Antibiotic = 'Amikacin' 
    THEN Mode_Antibiotic 
  END) Antibiotic1,
  MAX(CASE 
    WHEN Mode_Antibiotic = 'Amikacin' 
    THEN Mode_Qualifier 
  END) Qualifier1,
  MAX(CASE 
    WHEN Mode_Antibiotic = 'Amikacin' 
    THEN Mode_MIC 
  END) MIC1,
  MAX(CASE 
    WHEN Mode_Antibiotic = 'Ampicillin' 
    THEN Mode_Antibiotic 
  END) Antibiotic2,
  MAX(CASE 
    WHEN Mode_Antibiotic = 'Ampicillin' 
    THEN Mode_Qualifier 
  END) Qualifier2,
  MAX(CASE 
    WHEN Mode_Antibiotic = 'Ampicillin' 
    THEN Mode_MIC 
  END) MIC2,
  -- repeat 12 times with the remaining antibiotics
FROM t
GROUP BY ClinicalTrialID;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for he code Oleg, This approach certainly works. I may need to tweak it somewhat as the name of the antibiotics may vary from ClinicalTrialID to ClinicalTrialID.